# Windows powershell and cmd not loading properly (W11)

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, terminal

So my terminal was working completely fine this afternoon. I turn it on in the evening to work on a flutter project. After trying to run my file, I realised that the VScode terminal was unable to run flutter commands. I launch the windows terminal app to try to identify the problem but my powershell and cmd doesn't even load. [This is a screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u0qT.png) If I leave the app as it is, powershell exits with:

`[process exited with code 3221225786]`

I also tried launching cmd but the window only shows up after 10 minutes. The only fix to get my terminal working was running terminal as an administrator. After running the terminal app as an administrator, powershell and cmd load fine. However, running the flutter command does nothing as it just hangs. Other commands like node and adb seem to work fine though. Is this a path issue?

It might also be worth mentioning that the commands end up working eventually. Although this was not the case a few hours ago when everything ran immediately.

edit:
I'd like to add that once powershell / cmd loads, the issue does not repeat itself until I reboot. The same goes for my commands that just hang. They also all load at the same time. So if I were to try to launch cmd and also run a command in powershell, they would hang for an extended amount of time and eventually the cmd window would show up and the command would run at the same time.

Could this be a permission issue? I just tried to run another flutter command that failed because it couldn't access file or directory. Are my files somehow locked? I'm using an admin account.

Comment: If you avoid using Windows Terminal are you able to launch PowerShell? What versions of PowerShell do you have installed. Be as specific as possible

Comment: I've seen something weird like this myself once. I fixed it by rebooting my computer. Never happened again.

Comment: Code `3221225786` is in hex code `0xC000013A` which means `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT`. Did you press Ctrl-C? Did you update anything on the computer before turning the computer off? Can you see any update in Windows Update history? Are your computer and VScode  fully updated?

Comment: Only the default windows powershell and command prompt gives me the not loading problem as shown in the image. I also have 7.2.1 installed and that works fine. I've rebooted the computer a few times to test out the issue and its pretty consistent. I still can't run certain commands that have been added to path although as mentioned, they end up working eventually somehow.

Comment: Try deleting the Windows Terminal profile file (i.e. `settings.json`)

Comment: I've deleted the terminal settings.json. It doesn't seem to have done anything. The problems with cmd and powershell still persist. Although powershell 7.2.1 loads perfectly fine as usual. I don't think its an issue with the terminal app. Could some file somewhere have gotten corrupt? I've noticed my file explorer doing that slow indexing thing where it loads slowly (sometimes) when I open some files like downloads which its never done before for common folders.

Comment: The VScode terminal seems buggy to me too even on Windows 10 with PowerShell logic. I use PowerShell ISE instead and it works fine for me. I develop more task based stuff though than true programs so I don't use Visual Studio often but do wish I had more time to. As soon as I noticed a few bugs running PS logic with VS, I quit using it for PS script development. @Emmanuel

Comment: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/problems-with-antimalware-defender-update-4-18-2202-4.5218/ this might be related to the issue although the problem disappeared today.